# Pass parameter to SSHSparkSubmitOperator Operator

Tags: airflow

Suppose there is  file which will have spark configuration parameters like # of executors, executor memory. In the airflow workflow 1st task will read the file get the above parameters and  pass to SSHSparkSubmitOperator operators in the executor_memory=<some_variable>,                                       num_executors=<some_variable>

Is there a way we can accomplish this?

Comment: How about airflow variables ? Will that work for you ?

Comment: If that is fine. then you can load it to airflow variables using json file and airflow cli commands

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon Looks like the arguments in question (`executor_memory`, `num_executors`) aren't templated though unfortunately.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon Thanks i have created JSON variable and it worked

Comment: If the airflow variables worked for you let me know.